# How to import data from web api to normal cell

Tags: excel, vba, api

I want get value from api to my table.
My table look like this.
[image]
And i want add value to profit from steam api
I found steam api [https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=Sticker%20|%20OG%20(Holo)%20|%202020%20RMR](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=Sticker%20%7C%20OG%20(Holo)%20%7C%202020%20RMR)
I try inport data from this but everytime exel create new sheet. This is first problem.
The second problem is that it only needs one value - median_price from this api not all.

I try import this but every time this opening in new sheet.
[image]

Comment: Learn about the [XMLHTTP Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760305(v=vs.85)). `Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")` and `http.Open "GET", URL, False` and `http.Send` then check `http.responsetext`

Comment: If you receive the data as xml you can parse it using an xml document object `Set  xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` and `xmlDoc.LoadXML http.responsetext`

Comment: ...and if the data is JSON then use VBA-JSON   https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON